# SAP HANA custom dictionary: full-text-index not generated or updated

Tags: dictionary, hana

There are two problems with SAP HANA custom dictionaries.

1. Updating and recompiling the dictionary has no effect on the full-text-index table (even by dropping and generating the full-text-index again)
2. using custom dictionaries & configuration may lead to an empty fulltext-index-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the 1. Problem**

deleting the configuration file and replace it with a new file (same content but different file name) then activating all changes (activates the deletion of the old config and adds the new config) seems to be a work-around.

Note: this means you also have to change the configuration name in the SQL command.

**For the 2. Problem**

Check this trace file:

```
/usr/sap/HDB/HDB00/hanadb/trace/preprocessor_alert_hanadb.trc
```

This error message:

```
File read Error '/usr/sap/HDB/SYS/global/hdb/custom/config/lexicon//EXTRACTION_CORE_MOD2', error='Storage object does not exist: $STORAGEOBJECT$'
```

occurs if the configuration file EXTRACTION_CORE_MOD2 is not properly activated in the repository under sap.hana.ta.config. So double check the repository if the configuration file exists in the specified path.

Answer (score -1):

For the first problem, I have the same scenario in which I need to make some changes in the custom dictionary and activated it. It did not affect my index table unit I run the following statement:

```
ALTER INDEX MYINDEX REBUILD;
```

I have checked it and the changes affect the index table by this statement. So you do not have to remove your index or save the changes of your custom dictionary in a file with new name.

Comment: This deletes the index in my case. So not a solution.